# How to extend background to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

How can I make the white box (container) extend fully to the bottom of the page?

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);

html,body 
{
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

body.app 
{
    background: #8e44ad;
}

div.container 
{
    margin: 25px 25px 0px 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    min-height: 96vh;
    background: #fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="app">
    <div class="container">
        <header></header>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `height: 100%;` to your container?

Comment: Yea I tried but that didn't make sense to the page.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/0aa9xtpz/

Remove the `height: 100%;` from `html` and give `body` `margin: 0;`.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6b6jor I don't see a gap on Firefox (36.0), Chrome (40.0.2214.115), or Safari (8.0.3) on Mac. Is the gap present in the jsfiddle for you? Can you post your modified source so we can make sure there isn't something else in your css that's interfering?